# haskell, the same program using monads

Tags: haskell, monads

As you can see, I wrote program, e.g:

> test "12 124 212" = Right [12, 124, 212]
>
> test "43 243 fs3d 2" = Left "fs3d is not a number"

```
test :: String -> Either String [Int]
test w = iter [] $ words w
    where
        iter acc []     = Right (reverse acc)
        iter acc (x:xs) = if (all isDigit x) then
                              iter ((read x):acc) xs
                          else
                              Left (x++ "is not a number")
```

A am starting learning monads.  Could you show me how to implement it using monads ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse)/[`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) (they're the same for lists). Also you can use [`readEither`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readEither) for simplification:

```
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
import Data.Bifunctor (first)
import Text.Read (readEither)

test :: String -> Either String [Int]
test = traverse parseItem . words

parseItem :: String -> Either String Int
parseItem x = first (const $ x++" is not a number") $ readEither x
```

So what does `mapM` do? It basically implements the recursion over the list that you did manually. However, unlike the standard `map` function it takes a monadic function (`parseItem` in our case, where `Either String` is a monad) and applies one step on the list after the other:

```
iter [] = Right []
iter (x:xs) = do
  r <- parseItem x
  rs <- iter xs
  return (r:rs)
```

Comment: Why you aplicate two arguments for readEither ? It takes only one (String) argument

Comment: @HaskellFun: Thanks. I somehow expected it to take the error message and the string to be parsed. Fixed now using the [amazing Bifunctors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:first) :-)

Comment: It doesn't work as my soltuion. It returns parse error without wrong string

Comment: thanks, could you give me some comment how does it work ?

Comment: @HaskellFun: Oh my, I thought it would return the input string in the `Left` value, but apparently it gets its own error messages. Well, we can fix that as well…

Comment: @HaskellFun: Which part, the `traverse`?

Comment: Yes, traverse and first

Comment: You should not care about `first` and `const`. Maybe I got a bit carried away with this… you can easily implement `parseItem` using your old code with the `if all isDigit x`. It's short for `case readEither x of Left _ -> x++"…"; Right i -> Right i`

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me how to implement it without `traverse` ? (for example using `(>>=)`

Comment: @HaskellFun: See the version with the `do` notation in the end of the answer. I think it's a good excercise to [convert that to `>>=`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monads_as_computation#Do_notation) yourself :-) Notice I've left out `words` there for simplicity

Answer (score 2):

Bergi's answer is just right, but maybe you'll find it easy to understand presented this way:

```
test :: String -> Either String [Int]
test str = traverse parseNumber (words str)

parseNumber :: String -> Either String Int
parseNumber str
    | all isDigit str = Right (read str)
    | otherwise       = Left (str ++ " is not a number")
```

The other thing I'd recommend is don't write tail-recursive accumulator loops like `iter` in your example.  Instead, look at library documentation and try to find list functions that do what you want.  In this case, as Bergi correctly pointed out, `traverse` is exactly what you want.  It will take some study to get fully comfortable with this function, though.  But given how the `Monad` instance of `Either` and the `Traversable` instance of lists work, the `traverse` in this example works like this:

```
-- This is the same as `traverse` for lists and `Either`
traverseListWithEither :: (a -> Either err b) -> [a] -> Either err [b]
traverseListWithEither f [] = Right []
traverseListWithEither f (a:as) =
    case f a of
      Left err -> Left err
      Right b  -> mapEither (b:) (traverseListWithEither f as)

-- This is the same as the `fmap` function for `Either`    
mapEither :: (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b
mapEither f (Left e)  = Left e
mapEither f (Right a) = Right (f a)
```